# ActiveRecord query with conditionals on nested associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations

I've got a Person model, who has_many roles, and roles, in turn, belong_to an application. I'd like to query all the roles a person has for a given application. So far I've got:

```
p = Person.includes(:roles => [:application]).where(:loginid => 'their_loginid', :roles => {:application_id => 1})
```

Which works, but it's querying based on Person.roles.application_id; instead, I'd like to query based on Person.roles.application.api_key (another property of an application).

I tried:

```
p = Person.includes(:roles => [:application]).where(:loginid => 'their_loginid', :roles => {:application => {:api_key => 'the_api_key'}})
```

but I receive the error that:

```
no such column: application.api_key
```

leading me to think my usage of ActiveRecord isn't joining the tables together correctly.

Any ideas?

Comment: try Person.includes(:roles => [:application]).where(:loginid => 'their_loginid', :roles => {:application => {:api_key => 'the_api_key'}}).to_sql to understand what it's happening

Comment: What's strange is that running the query and using .to_sql give different results:

.to_sql: "SELECT \"people\".* FROM \"people\" WHERE \"people\".\"loginid\" = 'their_loginid' AND \"application\".\"api_key\" = \"the_key\""

while the SQLite3 exception error is quite long.

It does appear that a join on the application table is missing though I don't know why.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
p = Person.includes(:roles => [:application]).where(:loginid => 'their_loginid', :role_id => Application.find_by_api_key('api_key').role_ids)
```

Comment: Though it seems unnecessary, what I want to do is something like:

`Person.joins(:roles => [:application]).where(:loginid => 'cthielen', :roles => {:application => {:id => 1}}`

which doesn't work.

(I'm going to query for a non-id element, api_key, part of application, which is why I need that extra bit of nesting.)

Comment: Thanks for the help. I did get it working via: Person.joins(:roles => [:application]).where(:loginid => 'their_loginid', :roles => {:applications => {:api_key => 'the_api_key'}})

Comment: Oops, not quite there yet. I did get it working via: Person.joins(:roles => [:application]).where(:loginid => 'their_loginid', :roles => {:applications => {:api_key => 'the_api_key'}}) but for some reason that does not actually return the roles associated with that application. E.g. p = Person.find_by_loginid("their_id") will return a valid p.roles but the query above gives me an error on p.roles. How do I include the roles associated with that application_id?

Comment: Still not working with the change to includes(), the query doesn't error out but p.roles (p = Person...) still does not exist:

`p = Person.includes(:roles => [:application]).where(:loginid => 'their_loginid', :roles => {:applications => {:api_key => 'the_api_key'}}).to_sql
 => "SELECT \"people\".* FROM \"people\" WHERE \"people\".\"loginid\" = 'their_loginid' AND \"applications\".\"api_key\" = 'the_api_key'"`

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
p = Person.joins.includes(:roles => [:application]).where(:loginid => 'their_loginid', :roles => {:application => {:api_key => 'the_api_key'}})
```

In my case it woks.